# Unity 2021.3.19f1 - player not jumping

Tags: unity-game-engine

in Unity 2021.3.19f1 , I created the following basic script to let the player move left and right and jump :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyPlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    float moveSpeed ;
    float jumpForce;
    float moveHorizontal;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        moveSpeed = 0.5f;
        jumpForce = 8f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        if (moveHorizontal > 0.1f || moveHorizontal < 0.1f)
        {
            rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(moveHorizontal * moveSpeed, rb2D.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(rb2D.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that, if I keep pressed **together both the left arrow button and the up arrow button** (I will need to be able to press both them for new features I will add in the future), **I am not able to jump at all**.
If I test the same thing on the right side (that is to say I keep pressed together both the right arrow and up urrow), I am able to jump without problems.
Is anything I am doing wrong or could be my Unity installation is corrupted or can be a Unity bug?
Thank you, Regards

Comment: Some keyboards dot not properly handle pressing multiple keys at the same time. It could be that your code and unity installation is fine, but your keyboard is just not sending through all of your key presses. I found this tool online https://en.key-test.ru/ check that both the left and up arrow keys light up green when you press them at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your help  @Dutchen18 , you are right!! It seems a issue related to my keyboard. That tool shows me that when I keep pressed the left and up button together, the space bar button pression event is not sent . I will try changing keyboard